# Storing and displaying a grid of buttons / multiple layouts

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a point of sale application using WPF with MVVM.

One of the features is that there will be a grid/panel on the screen with say for example 10 x 10 buttons, 1 button per stock item for example.

What I need to do is to allow the user to create a new layout or edit an existing layout where they can add a new button or remove a button etc..

So in theory the user can have a number of different layouts where they can select from to show on the screen.

Each of the buttons will be linked to a stock product in the database and will have properties like colour, text, image etc..

So I am thinking if I have a user control set to 10 x 10 buttons or use a Uniform Grid, I could bind to a collection of buttons. I was also thinking of storing each layout button for each layout as XML and reading this to create some kind of collection and binding that to the grid.

For example the user could at point have the choice of choosing between 10 different screen/ grid layouts, each layout having its own set of buttons which could be in different positions, or have different text etc..

My question is, is this the best approach to store the buttons and layouts as XML?
And how could i directly bind a grid/uniform grid to a collection of buttons?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall approach looks fine to me. As for binding button collection to grid, you can use `ItemsControl` with custom `ItemsPanel` template for this:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="10" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button>
                    <!-- bind button color, content, etc -->
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```